# Implement Seq2Seq in Keras with Image Seqs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I have a problem with input as a sequence of images, and output as a sequence of labels, which correspond to each frame in the image. The input format is illustrated as below:

[image]

**Goal:** Predict a list of labels `[label 0, label 1, label 2, label 3]` based on the list of input sequence `[img 0, img 1, img 2, img 3]`. The output of training model should be:

`P([label 0, label 1, label 2, label 3]/[img 0, img 1, img 2, img 3])`.

The `label 0` depends on `img 0`, and is also correlated with `img 1, img 2 and img 3`. And other labels depend on all images in the input sequence as well. So, this makes a target label depends on both spatial information in each single image and temporal information.

So, I plan to **use Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) to encoder the spatial info** for each img. In the same time, **How can I encode the temporal info of the img sequence with LSTM?**

Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, LSTM, Flatten, TimeDistributed, RepeatVector
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

def cnn_lstm():

    model = Sequential()

    # CNN module
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = 8, 
                                    kernel_size = (2, 2), 
                                    padding = 'same',
                                    activation='relu',
                                    name = 'Conv_1'),
                                    input_shape = (None, img_height, img_width, channels)))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization(name='BN_1')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D()))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = 8, 
                                    kernel_size = (2, 2), 
                                    padding = 'same',
                                    activation='relu',
                                    name = 'Conv_2')))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization(name='BN_2')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D()))

    # Flatten all features from CNN before inputing them into LSTM
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

    # LSTM module
    model.add(LSTM(50))
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_seq_length))

    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, name = 'decoder'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

`output_seq_length = 4` and `nb_classes = 4` in this example.

**Will my model achieve what I expected?**

If it is a **seq2seq problem**, it does not look like there is "teacher forcing" involved, as showed in this [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

Is there a way to take advantage of CNN to encode spatial info and LSTM to encode temporal info at the same time? Like a **combination of CNN and encoder-decoder LSTM**?

Any inputs are welcome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your model will work, but you can improve your LSTMs by using [Bidirectional](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#bidirectional) wrapper to accumulate information both ways. You also don't want to compress the first LSTM and also return sequences as you are labelling every image.

A combination of CNN and LSTM? Well Keras has a [ConvLSTM2D](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d) layer that would apply convolutions to input and recurrent components.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please elaborate "You also don't want to compress the first LSTM and also return sequences"? If I return the sequences in the first LSTM, I am not using it in the 2nd LSTM. Then will the `return_sequences=True` help?

Comment: You want to use return_sequences for both LSTMs so all the images are not encoded / compressed into a single vector. Instead, you return a hidden state for every image in both layers.

Comment: in my code, `model.add(LSTM(50))` only returns final cell state as a vector with 50 elements.  if I use `return_sequences=True` for the 1st LSTM, I will obtain the output of LSTM at each time step. What you suggest is to have the return_sequences, and use them in the 2nd LSTM? How do I use both `return_sequences` and `final cell state` as input it the 2nd LSTM?

Comment: @Jundong Did you finally solve your question? and want to share your solution?

Comment: I am sorry, @TheJokerAEZ, I did not solve this problem.